# R tidyverse getting NA values

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I get all rows that contain any NA values in a dataframe using tidyverse syntax?

I was googling this, but have find it difficult to find an answer.

Comment: `NULL` is different than `NA`. What are you looking for? Can you provide an example and show expected output based on that?

Comment: When I call `sum(is.na(data))` in my dataframe it says I have 286 values that are NA. I'm just trying to see those rows which are NA.

Comment: `data[rowSums(is.na(data)) > 0, ]` Or in `tidyverse` , `data %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.